# Applications to (not of) category theory.

Tags: category-theory

Very frequent question is "How category theory can help other mathematical areas?". I want to reverse it and ask: are there results in CT which can be obtained more easily by using methods from other mathematical subjects? Are such things as, say, combinatorial CT possible?

Comment: ?https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory

Comment: For example the diagram chasing lemmas for Abelian categories can be obtained more easily for modules with flesh-and-blood elements, and then one can involve Mitchell's embedding theorem..

Comment: Combinatorial category theory : http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/whitepoint/euler.pdf  (by Tom Leinster, this is about the Euler characteristic of a category)

Comment: What do you mean by combinatorial category theory?